# How can i use draw gizmos to draw dots between each waypoints?

Tags: unity, c#

```
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;

        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, target.position);
        }
    }
```

Before that i'm not sure how to draw at all between all the waypoints.

Instead line maybe to draw spheres or something else and scale it to dots/points ? And i also want to be able to set and change the number of dots/points between each two waypoints.

For example from waypoints[0] to waypoint[1] to draw 30 dots and from waypoints[1] to waypoints[2] 10 dots or just the same maount of dots between all waypoints.

For not not curves lines only straight lines like showing the path between the waypoints in game view.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a theory about how to do this: drawing small spheres at evenly spaced positions between each pair of waypoints. Have you tried putting this theory into practice?

Comment: But how do i draw multiple spheres ? If i'm doing for example: for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) and then: Gizmos.DrawSphere(new Vector3(waypoints[0].transform.position.x * 5, waypoints[0].transform.position.y, waypoints[0].transform.position.z), 0.3f); it will draw one sphere just will change it's position and not draw 10 spheres.

Comment: Are you literally drawing the sphere at `waypoint[0]` every time, not `waypoint[i]`?

Comment: Yes at waypoints[0] it was just for testing i wanted to draw for testing 10 sphers from waypoints[0] on x every 5 space.  So i did * 5 but it's just changing the sphere position not drawing 10 spheres. Before that i was literally over the waypoints[i] and i did draw spheres on each waypoint but not sure how to draw more spheres between them like a path  route.

Comment: Well, you made a sphere for each waypoint by looping over the waypoints. Could you not make a sphere for each point in between by adding a second loop? ;)

Comment: I did: Gizmos.DrawSphere(new Vector3(waypoints[i].transform.position.x, 1, waypoints[j].transform.position.z), 0.3f); inside a nested loop like in LinkWindcrafter solution but it's still not good.

Answer (score 3):

If you found methods such as **DrawLine**, then you would find more methods on the [Gizmos API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html), such as **DrawWireSphere** and **DrawSphere**. You should always consult Unity's API.

To draw lines between each waypoint, it's easy, the number of lines, or intermediates of a number of waypoints its always **(the number of waypoints) - 1**, so you cando something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _waypointsQuantity; i++)
    {
        for(int j = (i + 1); j < _waypointsQuantity; j++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawLine(_waypointsPositions[i], _waypointsPositions[j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @LinkWindcrafter.
Just the other way around. As you need to draw dots, relatively close to spheres.

```
float radiusOfDot = 0.1f;
//if you want to add spacing, just iterate i = i+2
for(int i = 0; i < _waypointsQuantity; i++) 
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(_waypointsPositions[i], radiusOfDot );
}
```